# Need to create a pannable viewport within a page

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a custom map / diagram using jQuery / HTML / CSS. It is large, about 3000 x 3000 pixels of content overall. Because of this, I want to be able to restrict the viewable area to only 700x400 pixels or so, and let users pan within the div (by clicking and dragging) to move around the map and see the parts they desire.

The map will have many media elements within it, so using the GMaps API will not work for a variety of reasons. Also, the map is more than just an IMG element, so many of the "pan full size image" type plugins for jQuery that I've seen do not work for this purpose.

Seems like it should be relatively simple, but I searched quite a bit to no avail.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 1):

You could use a jquery pan/crop plugin:

- http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/pan
- http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/pan-zoom/
- http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html

They work for images, but I think you could adapt them to be used on any element

Hope this helps. Cheers